# OpenCV: imdecode image from memory returns None

Tags: python, opencv

Answered Edit: Dima solved my issue, I was unnecessarily calling cv2.decode for data that could be passed directly to OpenCV.

First, I'm pretty new to Python and OpenCV so apologies if I'm missing something obvious, which I'm almost certain I am. I'm trying to use Python to grab a screenshot from a specific window then pass that to OpenCV. If I write the screenshot out to disk then read it back, everything is fine, but as I want to be analyzing multiple screenshots per second, waiting on disk IO seems silly. Unfortunately I've spent about 4 hours trying everything I came up with searching around and nothing has solved the problem. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import win32gui
import win32ui
from ctypes import windll
import os
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Sword' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            lParam.append(hwnd)

def screenGrab(rect):
    im = ImageGrab.grab(rect)
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\game__' + str(int(time.time())) +
'.png', 'PNG')

def main():
    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, hwnds)
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnds[0])
    w = rect[2] - rect[0]
    h = rect[3] - rect[1]

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnds[0])
    mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnds[0], saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0)
    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

    im.save('thistest.png')

    img = cv2.imread('thistest.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    if img is not None:
        print(img.shape)
        print(type(img))
        cv2.imshow('FRAME', img)
        cv2.waitKey()

    im2 = np.frombuffer(bmpstr, dtype='uint8')

    im2.shape = (bmpinfo['bmHeight'], bmpinfo['bmWidth'], 4)

    img2 = cv2.imdecode(im2, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    if img2 is not None:
        print(img2.shape)
        print(type(img2))
        cv2.imshow('FRAME', img2)
        cv2.waitKey()

    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnds[0], hwndDC)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The only piece that sticks out to me is that if I print out the size/shape of bmpstr, it shows something like 1000,1600,3. However, after using numpy.frombuffer I'm unable to reshape to 1000,1600,3 and instead have to use 4 as it will complain about the size. When looking at the len of bmpstr it would show ~6400000 so the math makes sense that you need "4" dimensions, but bmpstr shows the same size with 3. I figured this meant somehow bmpstr was counting from 0, fine, but why can't I do the same with numpy.shape/reshape?

Anyway that's my only guess as to what's going wrong and could be entirely off base. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I believe Dima is on the right track pointing out I need to convert from RGB to BGR. Unfortunately I tried more than a few methods but still cannot make this work. Here is my current code. If I uncomment im.save, the image is written successfully.

```
from PIL import Image
import win32gui
import win32ui
from ctypes import windll
import os
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Sword' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            lParam.append(hwnd)

def main():
    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, hwnds)
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnds[0])
    w = rect[2] - rect[0]
    h = rect[3] - rect[1]

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnds[0])
    mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)
    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnds[0], saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0)
    if (result):
        bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
        bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

        #im.save('thistest.png')

        im2 = np.array(im)
        #im2 = im2[..., :2]
        im2 = im2[:, :, ::-1].copy()
        img2 = cv2.imdecode(im2, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        if img2 is not None:
            cv2.imshow('FRAME', img2)
            cv2.waitKey()
        else:
            print('img2 was empty')

        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
        saveDC.DeleteDC()
        mfcDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnds[0], hwndDC)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think Windows saves screendumps with Alpha, so you may need `Image.frombuffer('RGBA',...)` to make 4 channels

Comment: Not sure which part you're commenting on. The "im" object which receives my existing Image.frombuffer is working fine, that is the one that gets written to disk at the moment while I'm figuring stuff out. img2 from cv2.imdecode further along is what's not working. I just tried taking the functional im object, using im.tobytes to feed into cv2.imdecode to see if I got a different result, but the same thing happens - cv2.imdecode returns None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you have `im`, which is of type `PIL.Image`, you can instantly convert it to numpy and thus OpenCV like this

```
img = np.array(im)
# In case it is needed to get rid of alpha channel, if it is present
img = img[..., :2]
# To convert RGB to BGR 
img = img[:, :, ::-1].copy()
cv2.imshow('FRAME', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

In general, using `PIL` to decode images and then OpenCV to process them is a common practice.

Comment: I feel like the conversion from RGB to BGR is what I'm missing, but unfortunately I couldn't get anywhere from your example. I updated my question with my current code.

Comment: I've updated my code to illustrate you can directly use this image for imshow

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't realize decode could be skipped. I've got it working now based on your example.